# Implement rate limiting by cookie ID

Tags: java

I want to develop a simple in-memory web request rate limiting module, I am allowed to have 50 requests from each unique cookie ID every 60 seconds.

I am wondering if the following code is an optimal way of implementing such functionality:

```
class RateLimiter {

    private static final int MAX_REQUESTS = 50;

    private Map<String, List<Long>> cookieMap = new HashMap<>();

    private boolean isRateLimited(String cookieId) {
      long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
      long oldestTime = time - 60000;
      List<Long> timestamps = cookieMap.getOrDefault(cookieId, new LinkedList<>());
      timestamps.add(0, time);
      int count = 0;
      int tooOldIndex = -1;
      for (int i = 0; i < timestamps.size(); i++) {
          if (timestamps.get(i) >= oldestTime) {
              count++;
          } else {
              tooOldIndex = i;
              break;
          }
      }
      List<Long> newTimestamps = new LinkedList<>();
      // clean up timestamps older than the 60 second window
      for (int i = 0; i < tooOldIndex; i++) {
          newTimestamps.add(timestamps.get(i));
      }
      cookieMap.put(cookieId, newTimestamps);
      if (count >= MAX_REQUESTS) {
         return false;
      } else {
         return true;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just as a note, it's quite trivial to write a bot that disregards sending this cookie along, making it difficult or impossible to track via a cookie. If you have an auth token required, that could be tracked instead. If not, rate-limiting by IP address is a decent (but not perfect) solution.

Comment: Have you tested this? Does it actually work? I don't see how the list of a `cookieId` will ever contain anything. It seems you always end up storing an empty list, and it cannot grow

Comment: Why `LinkedList`?

Answer (score 10):

Accessing elements of a linked list with `.get(i)` is expensive, because it's an \$O(N)\$ operation compared to \$O(1)\$ of array backed structures. You should avoid doing this, and use an enhanced for-each loop instead, for example:

```
for (Long currentTimeStamp : timestamps) {
    if (currentTimeStamp  >= oldestTime) {
        newTimestamps.add(currentTimeStamp);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

If you need the element index, you can add a counting variable "manually" (declared before the loop, and increments in the loop body).

Answer (score 8):

> ```
>   if (count >= MAX_REQUESTS) {
>      return false;
>   } else {
>      return true;
>   }
> ```

This bit looks like it could be simplified to a simple `return` statement, by reverting the condition:

```
return count < MAX_REQUESTS
```

That said, are you sure you want to return `false` when `count` is equal to `MAX_REQUESTS`? The *actual* maximum number of requests is `MAX_REQUESTS - 1` otherwise...

Answer (score 7):

You are iterating twice over `timestamps` which isn't necessary at all, because you can just add each item which meets the criteria `timestamps.get(i) >= oldestTime` to the `newTimestamps` like so

```
  List<Long> newTimestamps = new LinkedList<>();
  newTimestamps.add(time);
  for (int i = 0; i < timestamps.size(); i++) {
      Long currentTimeStamp = timestamps.get(i);
      if (currentTimeStamp  >= oldestTime) {
          newTimestamps.add(currentTimeStamp);
      } else {
          break;
      }
  }
  cookieMap.put(cookieId, newTimestamps);
```

So there is no cleaning up needed anymore. You need neither the `count` nor the `tooOldIndex` variable, so I have removed both. You can simply evaluate the return value by checking `size` of the `newTimestamps`.

---

After taking a second look at your code I recognized that the method `isRateLimited()` has side effects which a caller of this method wouldn't expect. If one calls a method like `boolean isXXX()` he/she wouldn't expect that some state would be changed like the `cookieMap` in that method.

I would suggest splitting this method into several methods like so (also taking into account the answers of @janos, @Mat'sMug and @ AndriyKryvtsun)

```
private List<Long> getTimestampRange(String cookieId, Long maxTime) {

    List<Long> timeStampRange = new LinkedList<>();

    List<Long> timestamps = cookieMap.getOrDefault(cookieId, new LinkedList<>());

    for (Long currentTimeStamp : timestamps) {
        if (currentTimeStamp  >= oldestTime) {
            timeStampRange.add(currentTimeStamp);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return timeStampRange; 
}

private boolean isLimitExceeded(List<Long> timespans) {

    return timspans.size() > REQUESTS;
}

private boolean updateCookiesIfInRange(String cookieId) {
    Long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

    List<Long> timeStampRange = getTimestampRange(cookieId, time - 60000);
    if (isLimitExceeded(timeStampRange)) {
        return false;
    }

    timeStampRange.add(0, time);
    cookieMap.put(cookieId, timeStampRange);
    return true;
}
```

In this way the responsibilities are clearly separated but what I just recognized is a little bit strange. **How in the world should this method be called ?** Anything in this class is **`private`** !

Answer (score 7):

Conceptually your `RateLimiter` works incorrectly. You shouldn't put current `time` into `cookieMap` if your `isRateLimited` finally returns `false` because it's only **attempt** to request your server for the request execution. You shouldn't count it. You should keep in the map only successfully processed attempts.

Also I would reuse exist Google Guava [com.google.common.util.concurrent.RateLimiter](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html) implementation.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the points made in [the](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/122387/24141) [other](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/122379/24141) [excellent](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/122383/24141) [answers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/122381/24141)...

#### Java 8 way (or the highway)

There's a few Java 8 methods that you can use to do your computations in a more fluent manner. [`Map.computeIfAbsent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) returns you either the current (existing or computed) value associated with the key, so you do not have to `put()` the new `List` later:

```
List<Long> timestamps = cookieMap.computeIfAbsent(cookieId, k -> new ArrayList<>());
// do something with timestamps, which is a reference to the value in the map
```

You probably do not require the doubly-linked characteristics of a `LinkedList`.

Then, instead of finding the index where you want to trim away the 'older' timestamps, you can apply a [`Predicate<Long>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) using the [`Collection.removeIf(Predicate<T>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) method:

```
timestamps.removeIf(l -> l >= oldestTime);
```

There's also a better way to model timestamps than a simple `Long`, using an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html). This lets you work with more fluent time-based methods instead of simple arithmetic. For example, you can do something like this:

```
timestamps.removeIf(instant -> ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(instant, Instant.now()) >= 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to add one point missing from all current answers: Thread safety

If your code will be called by multiple threads at the same time you need to use different implementations of your `cookieMap` and potentially the lists in the map or make your method `synchronized`.

A simple way would be to wrap the map using [`Collections.synchronizedMap(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap-java.util.Map-) or to use a [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).

If multiple requests with the same `cookieId` may be processed at the same time and the lists are used as in your question you would need a synchronized list too, as the same list may be available to and modified by multiple threads. You can use [`Collections.synchronizedList(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList-java.util.List-) or e.g. a [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html).

Note that you don't need synchronized lists when you use the lists like in [the longer example of Heslachers answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/122381/73691) as only new lists are modified and put in the map, the lists in the map are never modified.

Note that even if you make your code "thread safe" (I don't like this term, because safety depends on context, IMO) by correctly synchronizing the map you could miss requests (and let more then 50 requests pass) or take not yet completed requests in the consideration (and deny requests while the limit is not yet reached), depending on the implementation.